# Construction of long texts in chapters inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

One of the views of my iOS app contains a quite long text inside a UIScrollView, with an user guide. The text is localized in three languages and splitted in chapters with titles.

I'm using multiple UITextView. At the end of each view constructor I'm adding it to the main view and I call:

`[self autoSizeTextView:myuitexview];`

to make it resize accordingly to the length of the text for the language in use.

The next UITextView is positioned calculating the position and the height of the previous one, to have them presented in order and not overlapped.

This is a tedious job! Considering that I don't want to use a web view (to keep good performances), is there an another way to display a long and not mono-block text (with chapters and a not so simple layout) on iOS?

Comment: what do you mean by tedious? you could probably subclass your scrollview to do your position calculation automatically based on the number of subviews it has.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I mean that I'm not comfortable with the idea that I have to add an UITextView for each "paragraph" I want to add to the text. In addiction of this, I can't find a way to add bolds or other formats to the text, without splitting it in more subviews, everytime a change in the formatting of the text occurs.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using UITableView? I'd suggest, instead of doing this in a UIScrollView, do it in a UITableView. It'd save your app some resources to do your positioning calculations, and the lazy loading of paragraphs will be taken care of by the cellForRowAtIndexPath, which will keep the app very responsive

Comment: I meant, save resources, instead of spending it on calculation positions.

Comment: Thank you calvinBhai! I did it with a customized UITableView, it worked! I can't mark your comment as best answer, do you want to make it an real answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from my comment:

Is there a reason for not using UITableView? I'd suggest, instead of doing this in a UIScrollView, do it in a UITableView. It'd save your app some resources to do your positioning calculations, and the lazy loading of paragraphs will be taken care of by the cellForRowAtIndexPath, which will keep the app very responsive

@flip79: glad it helped!